# How do I generate a regression equation from a dataset in R?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I have imported a dataset into a variable named "d", and I want to generate a linear function out of it:

```
d <- read.table("file_url")
```

I tried

```
lm(d[1] ~ d[2])
```

However the function lm doens't expect lists. What is the proper way of doing this?

fyi, the file is a simple txt file consisting of two columns of numbers. I want the second column to be the independent variable, and the first to be the dependent.

Comment: Most people would create a `data.frame`, apply any pre-processing needed on the data frame and then use the column names in the formula while passing the whole data frame in the `data` parameter to `lm`.

Comment: You can just do `lm(d[[1]] ~ d[[2]])`. `lm` can't handle lists, but you can extract the vectors from the list with the proper indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the names to create the regression

```
lm(reformulate(names(d)[2], names(d)[1]), data = d)
```

---

A reproducible example is

```
lm(reformulate(names(mtcars)[2], names(mtcars)[1]), data = mtcars)
```

Comment: How do I use a 90 percent confidence interval with regards to estimating the change of d2 vs d1?

Comment: @Jaigus  Can you please post as a new question with a reproducible example.  Not clear from the comments

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can achieve this using base R machinery:

```
lm(as.formula(paste0(names(d)[2], "~",names(d)[1])), data = d)
```

From the `lm` reference:

> **formula** an object of class "formula" (or one that can be coerced to that class): a symbolic description of the model to be fitted. The
> details of model specification are given under ‘Details’.
> ...
>
> Models for lm are specified symbolically. A typical model has the form
> response ~ terms

So, you need to create a model string according to the spec and convert it to formula.